# Paying taxes on a condo sale

Tags: taxes

How much tax will I have to pay on the money I cleared after selling my condo? How do I calculate it?

Comment: Country / State?  Might depend on the city too, though unlikely.

Answer (score 6):

If you are in the United States,  Real Estate gains are taxed as capital gains 15% [currently](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Capital_gains_tax_in_the_United_States) but will go up in 2011.

You may be able to exclude $250,000 filing single (500k married filing jointly) if you have lived in the condo 2 out of the last 5 years. See [IRS Publication 523](http://www.irs.gov/publications/p523/index.html) for more information.

You are only taxed on the profit from the sale. If you paid $100,000 and you sell it for $125,000 you would owe capital gains tax on $25,000 if you don't meet the conditions in IRS Publication 523.

Comment: "but will go up in 2011." - citation?

Comment: I linked to the article, click "currently" of course that is subject to change with  congress discussing the bill as I write this.

Comment: Capital gains rates are scheduled to go back to 2003 level ~25% but it seems like Congress is likely to pass some type of extension of the Bush era tax cuts which will probably keep capital gains at 15%.

Comment: Citiation? Pick your poison. http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=tax+rates+2010#sclient=psy&hl=en&tbs=nws:1&q=us+tax+rates+2011&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=55690f3549dbf15a -- right now the top result is this one, it's reasonably informative. http://www.cbsnews.com/8301-503544_162-20025888-503544.html

Comment: The cap gain rate was extended, through 2012. The citation linked in this answer reflects this as of 12/18.